# Get parent of term

Tags: timber

I might have missed it in the [Timber Docs](http://timber.github.io/timber/#timber-term) but is there a possibility to get the parent terms of a given taxonomy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two methods depending on Twig vs. PHP and what exactly you're looking to do.

Consider a post which as been assigned a category of "Politics" (which is a child category of "News")

### Example 1: Get a parent term in a Twig file

```
<p>Find more posts in {{ post.category.name }} and {{ post.category.parent.name }}</p>

<!--- outputs as ...  --->
<p>Find more posts in Politics and News</p>
```

### Example 2: Get the top-level terms from a taxonomy

```
$context['parent_categories'] = Timber::get_terms(array('taxonomy' => 'category', 'parent' => 0));
```

Use in Twig like...

```
Top-level categories for my site are...

{% for term in parent_categories %}
    <li><a href="{{ term.link }}">{{ term.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}

<!-- Outputs as... -->
<li><a href="/category/news/">News</a></li>
<li><a href="/category/sports/">Sports</a></li>
<li><a href="/category/opinions/">Opinion</a></li>
```

Comment: I meant it like in example 1 (I really must have missed the notification for this answer). Since you answered both ways which one could interpret my question I won't edit it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are trying to use the parent of a category in a twig view. That was the case I tried to solve when stumbling upon this post.

In `category.php` you can get the parent category by getting the parent category ID of the currently viewed category:

```
$category = new TimberTerm();
$context['category'] = $category;
if ($category->parent) {
    $context['parent_category'] = new TimberTerm($category->parent);
}
```

`$category->parent` corresponds to the ID of the parent category. It is `null` if the category doesn't have a parent. You can then use the resulting category in your template.

```
<a class="category_{{parent_category.slug|lower}}" href="{{parent_category.link}}">
    {{parent_category.title}}
</a>
```